# Unable to disable password authentication over SSH

Tags: ssh, login, 22.04, authentication

I configured login by SSH key which is working but I can still login by password, which I don't want.

I used `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config` to make the following changes:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

I disabled the root login because my user can log in.

It should refuse login with password but it still allows it.

My version of ssh is OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 on Ubuntu 22.04.

How do I disable the ability to login with password over SSH?

Comment: did you restart the ssh service? `sudo service ssh restart`

Comment: You may also need `ChallengeResponseAuthentication no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. To restart sshd: `sudo systemctl restart ssh`.

Comment: doesn't work. i inserted ChallengeResponseAuthentication no in /etc/ssh/sshd_config and restared the shh and down's work. like i sair in new answer. yes i did sudo service ssh restart

but is in the same... my vps in on Contabo.

I tried this on another vps on vultr, and it works... it disables the login with password. its possible the contabo has something configured?

Comment: The comments are our channel to ask you for clarifications. Please edit the question. Do not ask a new question in the comments or in the answer. Questions about any specific VPS like Contabo is off topic here. You have to ask them.

Comment: sorry. i already deleted the answer. i asked them, but they dont care and they take a long time to answer. but i think that i haved this well configured.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/727492/passwordauthentication-no-but-i-can-still-login-by-password

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I already resolved this issue. Inside the directory /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/ there is only one .conf file (50-cloud-init.conf), but inside it contains the line: PasswordAuthentication yes

I changed the line to #PasswordAuthentication yes

and i restarted the ssh. Now is working. I can only access with the ssh key.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't believe I wasted 3 hours over this looking for solutions. Thank you.

Comment: Many thanks for that, I was having the same issue and that also worked for me!

Comment: wow that's super annoying - thanks though you saved me a bunch of time!

Comment: Why would they ship it with an extra config file that overrides such a central setting from the base config file?

Comment: Speculating that your instance is in a cloud, like Vultr, and the cloud provider added this file.  Had the same problem here...

Comment: yes. OVHCloud..

Comment: The installer for Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 will also do this if you enable the "Allow password login" option during the OpenSSH setup page.

Comment: `PasswordAuthentication yes` is indeed configured inside of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/50-cloud-init.conf`. I have tried it on **Ubuntu 22.04.3** on a local VM installation.

That said, I found that `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/50-cloud-init.conf` is being referenced to in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

`Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf`

In my case, Im not using it, so I simply put a comment on that and it worked.